# Access Appium driver globally

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am new to Appium automation and trying to setup an automation framework using page object factory for my project. I have declared a class to deal with the starting of the appium server and initializing the Android webdriver, lets assume it to be class A. I have another class, class B where there are actual tests. Could you please guide on how to access the initialized appium driver in class A from class B. Please find below for details.

```
Class A{
AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver();
}
```

I am trying to use the driver object in class B something like this.

```
Class B{
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Is this feasible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Extend Class A to Class B. This should look something like this :

`Class B extends A 
{
}`

OR

2. Make driver variable **public static** and access driver in class B using class name dot (.) and variable name.

`Class A {  public static AndroidDriver; }`

```
Class B {    public void testMethod() {  A.driver.findElement(by); 
}
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the first solution, it worked with a minor modification. Class B extends A 
{
}

Answer (score 0):

- If you use same Spring, you can option for use @Componet with scope Application, after inject Object in your class test.
- This concept use for other framework same Seam, EJB each others.
- Solutions Vinod's that is valid